# Why do I get "./gettext.so: undefined symbol: PL_thr_key" when I try to use gettext in Lua?

Tags: perl, lua, gettext

I want to use the gettext library with Lua, but I get an undefined symbol error when I try to load it:

```
require('gettext')
error loading module 'gettext' from file './gettext.so':
    ./gettext.so: undefined symbol: PL_thr_key
stack traceback:
     [C]: in ?
     [C]: in function 'require'
     stdin:1: in main chunk
     [C]: in ?
```

`PL_thr_key` is defined in  perlapi.h, so this appears to be related to Perl.

Comment: Why did you tag with Perl?

Comment: Because gettext is using perl . From dynamic symbol table of gettext                                                                                            ..    12: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND PL_thr_key
13: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND Perl_sv_setpv
 14: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND Perl_sv_2pv_flags

Comment: Fair enough. Can you give a bit more context? What specific version of Lua, what version of the gettext enxtension (or whatever that is called in Lua), what version of the gettext library and so on.

Comment: Lua 5.3.2 , on 64-bit linux platform

Comment: It sounds like gettext was linked to a threaded perl, but you're running an unthreaded perl. How did you install gettext? How did you install perl? Do you have multiple versions of perl installed?

Comment: gettext came installed with linux  & Perl version is --  perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a module compiled against threaded Perl while your Perl installation is not threaded. Try to switch the version of Perl you're using.